# Unable to authenticate sending mail using smtpmail-send-it to gmail, "Username and Password not Accepted"

Tags: mu4e, smtpmail, passwords, authinfo

I would like mu4e to use smtpmail-send-it to send emails from emacs. I would like smtpmail-send-it to authenticate using [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/). I have 2factor auth on my gmail account, so I have to use an App Password.

My emacs verison is: GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2019-09-16

Based on what I've read of the [pass](https://github.com/DamienCassou/auth-password-store) app built into emacs, I've set up my `pass` directory as such:

```
Password Store
    smtp.gmail.com
        (user)@gmail.com
```

`(user)@gmail.com` looks like this:

```
(app password, copied from my security profile in google)
host: smtp.gmail.com
user: (user)@gmail.com
port: 465
```

I'm using this directory structure because later I'd like to add my work account, which also uses gmail.

Based on instruction from the above mentioned `pass` library, from the [emacs docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/auth.html#The-Unix-password-store) on auth-source, and from the mu4e manual, I've set up my config as follows (note spacemacs is involved, but I don't sense this is part of the issue) (this is not a raw copy/paste, I ripped out some stuff I thought unrelated, please ignore if there's mismatched parentheses or similar)

```
(setq smtpmail-stream-type 'tls)
(setq smtpmail-default-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com")
(setq smtpmail-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com")
(setq smtpmail-smtp-service 465)
(setq message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it )
(auth-source-pass-enable)
(setq auth-sources '(password-store))
(setq auth-source-debug t)
(setq auth-source-do-cache nil)

(with-eval-after-load 'mu4e
    (setq mail-user-agent 'mu4e-user-agent)
    (setq mu4e-user-mail-address-list '("((user)@gmail.com")
          )
    (setq mu4e-context-policy 'ask)
    (setq mu4e-contexts
          `( ,(make-mu4e-context
               :name "Personal"
               :match-func (lambda (msg)
                             (when msg
                               (string-match-p "^/gmailhome" (mu4e-message-field msg :maildir))))
               :vars '( ( user-mail-address     . "(user)@gmail.com"  )
                        (smtpmail-smtp-user . "(user)@gmail.com")
             ))
    )
```

The log shows the following:

```
Sending via mail...
auth-source-password-store: searching for ’(user)@gmail.com@smtp.gmail.com’ in entry names (user: (user)@gmail.com)
auth-source-password-store: no match found
auth-source-password-store: searching for ’smtp.gmail.com’ in entry names (user: (user)@gmail.com)
Decrypting /home/caleb/.password-store/smtp.gmail.com/(user)@gmail.com.gpg...done
auth-source-password-store: found 1 match: smtp.gmail.com/(user)@gmail.com
Decrypting /home/caleb/.password-store/smtp.gmail.com/(user)@gmail.com.gpg...done
auth-source-password-store: return (:host smtp.gmail.com :port 465 :user (user)@gmail.com) as final result (plus hidden password)
auth-source-search: found 1 results (max 1) matching (:host "smtp.gmail.com" :port "465" :user "(user)@gmail.com" :max 1 :require nil :create nil)
Decrypting /home/caleb/.password-store/smtp.gmail.com/(user)@gmail.com.gpg...done
smtpmail-send-it: Sending failed: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials s69sm87755otb.4 - gsmtp in response to AUTH PLAIN AHJvZ2Vyc2pjYWxlYkBnbWFpbC5jb20AeGZiZ2xyemtpZWRlZ3ZobA==
```

At first I thought this error was because I mistakenly put my normal gmail password into `pass`, but now I've swapped it for a fresh app password, and I'm still getting this error.

I looked through a couple other questions on here with similar issues, but none seemed to have similar reasons for authentication failure.

How can I successfully authenticate and send mail?

EDIT: I read on google's support that I might have a mismatch with my `(setq smtpmail-stream-type 'tls)` and the port number, `(setq smtpmail-smtp-service 465)`, so I changed to:

`(setq smtpmail-smtp-service 587)`

Now I'm getting the following error:

```
   Sending via mail...
    gnutls.el: (err=[-15] An unexpected TLS packet was received.) boot: (:priority NORMAL:%DUMBFW :hostname smtp.gmail.com :loglevel 0 :min-prime-bits 256 :trustfiles (/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt) :crlfiles nil :keylist nil :verify-flags nil :verify-error nil :callbacks nil)
gnutls-negotiate: GnuTLS error: #<process smtpmail>, -15
```

EDIT2: I changed to `starttls`

```
(setq smtpmail-stream-type 'starttls)
```

I also updated my `pass` entry to have `port: 587

And now am back to a user/password error.

Interestingly, the error appears to be identical to the same experiment as above, but when I forgot to change my `pass` entry's port. This makes me suspect that something's wrong with my pass config.

Error with wrong port in `pass`:

```
Sending via mail...
auth-source-password-store: searching for ’rogersjcaleb@gmail.com@smtp.gmail.com’ in entry names (user: rogersjcaleb@gmail.com)
auth-source-password-store: no match found
auth-source-password-store: searching for ’smtp.gmail.com’ in entry names (user: rogersjcaleb@gmail.com)
Decrypting /home/caleb/.password-store/smtp.gmail.com/rogersjcaleb@gmail.com.gpg...done
auth-source-password-store: found 1 match: smtp.gmail.com/rogersjcaleb@gmail.com
Decrypting /home/caleb/.password-store/smtp.gmail.com/rogersjcaleb@gmail.com.gpg...done
auth-source-password-store: return (:host smtp.gmail.com :port 465 :user rogersjcaleb@gmail.com) as final result (plus hidden password)
auth-source-search: found 1 results (max 1) matching (:host "smtp.gmail.com" :port "587" :user "rogersjcaleb@gmail.com" :max 1 :require nil :create nil)
Decrypting /home/caleb/.password-store/smtp.gmail.com/rogersjcaleb@gmail.com.gpg...done
535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials l24sm338725otf.59 - gsmtp
221 2.0.0 closing connection l24sm338725otf.59 - gsmtp
smtpmail-send-it: Sending failed: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials l24sm338725otf.59 - gsmtp in response to AUTH PLAIN AHJvZ2Vyc2pjYWxlYkBnbWFpbC5jb20AeGZiZ2xyemtpZWRlZ3ZobA==
```

Error with right port in `pass`

```
Sending via mail...
auth-source-password-store: searching for ’rogersjcaleb@gmail.com@smtp.gmail.com’ in entry names (user: rogersjcaleb@gmail.com)
auth-source-password-store: no match found
auth-source-password-store: searching for ’smtp.gmail.com’ in entry names (user: rogersjcaleb@gmail.com)
Decrypting /home/caleb/.password-store/smtp.gmail.com/rogersjcaleb@gmail.com.gpg...done
auth-source-password-store: found 1 match: smtp.gmail.com/rogersjcaleb@gmail.com
Decrypting /home/caleb/.password-store/smtp.gmail.com/rogersjcaleb@gmail.com.gpg...done
auth-source-password-store: return (:host smtp.gmail.com :port 587 :user rogersjcaleb@gmail.com) as final result (plus hidden password)
auth-source-search: found 1 results (max 1) matching (:host "smtp.gmail.com" :port "587" :user "rogersjcaleb@gmail.com" :max 1 :require nil :create nil)
Decrypting /home/caleb/.password-store/smtp.gmail.com/rogersjcaleb@gmail.com.gpg...done
535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials z13sm362612oth.10 - gsmtp
221 2.0.0 closing connection z13sm362612oth.10 - gsmtp
smtpmail-send-it: Sending failed: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials z13sm362612oth.10 - gsmtp in response to AUTH PLAIN AHJvZ2Vyc2pjYWxlYkBnbWFpbC5jb20AeGZiZ2xyemtpZWRlZ3ZobA==
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was solved when I manually edited my password in `pass` via `pass edit smtp.gmail.com/(user)@gmail.com to be equivalent to my app password that's stored elsewhere in`pass` for imap mail fetching.

I don't know why the newly created app password was invalid, and the old one is valid.

My config looks like the below now, and works:

```
Password Store
    smtp.gmail.com
      (user)@gmail.com
```

smtp.gmail.com/(username)@gmail.com/gpg

```
(old app password i was already using for IMAP)
host: smtp.gmail.com
user: (user)@gmail.com
port: 587
```

My emacs config:

```
(setq smtpmail-stream-type 'starttls)
(setq smtpmail-default-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com")
(setq smtpmail-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com")
(setq smtpmail-smtp-service 587)
(setq smtpmail-debug-info t)
(setq message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it )
(auth-source-pass-enable)
(setq auth-sources '(password-store))
(setq auth-source-debug t)
(setq auth-source-do-cache nil)
```

Comment: For me the solution was to set `(message-send-mail-function . message-send-mail-with-sendmail)`